# Why these two loss function are not the same?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, federated-learning

This is a loss function of a personalized federated learning framework. When lambda equals 0, all clients train locally. Otherwise they adjust their parameters based on the similarity to the global model.

Version 1, server returns the global_model to every client:

```
    def mtl_loss_fn(self, logits, labels, shared_model):
        sample_loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        mean_batch_term = sample_loss_fn(logits, labels)

        shared_model = shared_model.to(device='cuda')

        w_diff = torch.tensor(0., device=self.device)
        for w, w_t in zip(self.model.parameters(), shared_model.parameters()):
            w_diff += torch.pow(torch.norm(w - w_t), 2)

        prox_term = 0.5 * self.lam * w_diff
        # print(f"mean batch term: {mean_batch_term}, prox_term: {prox_term}")
        return mean_batch_term + prox_term
```

Version 2, server returns the parameters of the global_model to every client:

```
    def mtl_loss_fn(self, logits, labels, shared_model_parameters):
        sample_loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        mean_batch_term = sample_loss_fn(logits, labels)

        for x in shared_model_parameters:
            x.to(device='cuda')

        w_diff = torch.tensor(0., device=self.device)
        for w, w_t in zip(self.model.parameters(), shared_model_parameters):
            w_diff += torch.pow(torch.norm(w - w_t), 2)

        prox_term = 0.5 * self.lam * w_diff
        # print(f"mean batch term: {mean_batch_term}, prox_term: {prox_term}")
        return mean_batch_term + prox_term
```

Version 1 works well, but version 2 turns into completely local training no matter what lambda is.

I don't know why, they look the same to me..

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in shared_model_parameters:
        x.to(device='cuda')
```

Does not modify x in-place; instead, it returns a new tensor that has been moved to the specified device. You need to assign the value to a variable and pass that variable to the next step:

```
shared_model_parameters_cuda = [x.to(device='cuda') for x in shared_model_parameters]

w_diff = torch.tensor(0., device=self.device)
for w, w_t in zip(self.model.parameters(), shared_model_parameters_cuda):
    w_diff += torch.pow(torch.norm(w - w_t), 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply, I am testing your advice now. But why there isn't an error telling me self.model.parameters() and shared_model_parameters are not on the same device?

Comment: Hi, I got the results. It is still different from version 1.. so weird..

Comment: Hi, I tried moving the generator to gpu before this loss function. And the results are the same as version 1.

Comment: Hi, if modifying the code according to your advice, only the first data batch of the first client of every round gets the server's parameters, others don't go into this for loop. Moving the to-device action out of this loss function will do.